# Invoke a javascript object method from within a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, javascript-objects

I define the following `MyClass` and its methods in a user script:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myCallback = function() {
        alert("MyClass.myCallback()");
    };

    this.startRequest = function() {
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': "http://www.google.com/",
            'onload': function (xhr) {
                myClassInstance.myCallback();
            }
        });
    };
}

var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
myClassInstance.startRequest();
```

This script works and the `myCallback()` method gets called once the *GM_xmlhttpRequest* completes.

However, it only works because the `onload` callback is referring to the global variable `myClassInstance`. If I update the `onload` callback to:

```
'onload': function (xhr) {
    this.myCallback();
}
```

Then I get the (Chrome) error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'myCallback'.

It seems `this` is being evaluated in the wrong context.

Is there a way to invoke the `myCallback()` method of `myClassInstance` without having to resort to using a global variable?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Save the correct `this`, when it is in scope, into a variable. Then you can reference it later:

```
 this.startRequest = function() {
     var myself = this;
     GM_xmlhttpRequest({
         'method': 'GET',
         'url': "http://www.google.com/",
         'onload': function (xhr) {
             myself.myCallback();
         }
     });
 };
```

Comment: +1 You just ended my hour long head slamming session.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution, as already was pointed out, is creating an alias for the `this` that stays in scope. The most popular variable names for the alias are things like `self` or `that`, but anything works, really.

The other alternative (that might or might not be better, depending on the use case) is binding the method into a "plain" function and using that instead:

```
var f = this.callback.bind(this);

...
'onload': function(){
    f();
}
```

bind is not supported on old browsers, but you can find alternatives in many JS frameworks. The example I gave doesn't look that good, but it can be very convenient when you want to pass your method directly as a callback function (you might also get partial function application as well and that is very neat)

Comment: Be careful with `self` because of `window.self`.

Answer (score 3):

Store a reference to the instance and use it:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myCallback = function() {
        alert("MyClass.myCallback()");
    };

    var instance = this;

    instance.startRequest = function() {
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': "http://www.google.com/",
            'onload': function (xhr) {
                instance.myCallback();
            }
        });
    };
}
```